# Redirecting Wordpress posts to a custom php page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect Wordpress blog posts like for example http://www.maxprog.com/blog/?p=106 to a script I created that display the post: http://www.maxprog.com/site/blog/post.php?id=106

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/blog/?p=(.*)$ /site/blog/post.php?id=$1
RedirectMatch permanent ^/blog/index.php?p=(*)$ /site/blog/post.php?id=$1
RedirectMatch permanent ^/blog/(.*)$ /site/blog/post.php?id=$1
```

I want to redirect ?p=xxx pages only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not match against query string using mod-alias (RedirectMatch directive),  To manipulate query string, use mod-rewrite , add the following to your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ /site/blog/post.php?id=%1 [L,R]
```